# What is an efficient way to compare contents of two different objects / class instances in Java?

Tags: java

I have to compare the contents of two class instances: Not in entirety but certain fields. The classes are not identical; both the classes have different member elements.

Example:

```
Class Apple
{
  String a;
  String b;
  Object c;
  Object d;
  Object e;
}

Class Orange
{
 String x;
 String y;
 String z;
 Object p;
 Object q;
}
```

I would like to compare the value of string "a" in Apple with the value of a string in Class p.

An inefficient way to compare the contents would be to use the getter methods until I reach the value of interest.

What will be the efficient way of doing such type of comparisons on multiple fields and multiple times?

Comment: Why is it inefficient? What's class p?

Comment: If you know the value(s) of interest, why can't you just compare those directly?

Comment: Did you mean attribute "p" of an `Orange` rather than class `p`?

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you believe simply comparing them directly is inefficient? You tagged this question [tag:json] and [tag:testng] but don't mention either in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your getters are simply returning the values of the fields, and then they will be typically<sup>1</sup> be inlined.  If that happens, then your supposedly inefficient method of comparison is as efficient as it can be.

(Warning: your question "smells" of premature optimization.  Have you got hard evidence that these comparisons are *really* a performance bottleneck?  Have you profiled your code?  If not, there is a good chance you are trying to optimize something that doesn't matter.  And that would be *wasted effort*.)

However, if that is not good enough you could add a custom comparison method that tests only the fields that you are interested in; e.g.

```
public boolean myEquals(MyType other) {
    return this.field1.equals(other.field1) && this.field2 == other.field2;
}
```

Further optimization ideas:

1. Compare fields in an order where you test the fields that are most likely to be different first.
2. If comparing an object with itself is likely to happen frequently, consider using `this == other` as a short-circuit.
3. If the objects are likely to be tested repeatedly, and the result of any given comparison is likely to be false, consider adding a field to hold a custom hash field for (just) the fields you are testing, and using that as an accelerator.

But note that the ideas above only improve average performance in specific use-cases.  In others, they *could* make performance worse.

---

<sup>1 - A JIT compiler won't inline calls to methods that are too large, or that require dispatching; i.e. "virtual" function calls in C++ parlance.</sup>